How to make SPECINT2017 use a given share of CPU resources instead of all cores?
I want to test the relationship between a CPU's performance score and its utilization using the specint2017 benchmark. It is expected that the performance score will increase as the utilization increases, but the rate of increase will decrease. This is due to factors such as hyper-threading conflicts (lower ipc) and power constraints (lower frequency).
I used cgroup to limit the CPU usage of the SPECINT program, but I found that at 25% utilization, the power consumption decreased significantly compared to 100% utilization, but the instructions per cycle (IPC) and CPU frequency did not increase. This is not in line with expectations, and I suspect that there might be inter-process lock-stepping, where all testing processes start and sleep simultaneously, without truly staggering.
yum install libcgroup-tools
cgcreate -g cpu,cpuacct:mygroup
cgset -r cpu.cfs_quota_us=3200000 mygroup # using 32 cores（32 * 100 * 1000）
cgexec -g cpu,cpuacct:mygroup ./run_int_rate.sh

I tried adjusting the number of --copies, but this resulted in some cores being utilized at 100% while others remained idle, leading to uneven load distribution.
How could I configure SPECINT2017 to use a given share of CPU resources and ensure that the load is evenly distributed across logical cores and over time?
